# value range in a cell

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I am new to (google) spreadsheet and although i have looked on Google a lot and learned a lot I can't seem to find a way to:

1. indicate a range of values inside a cell (eg. 0.18 - 0.218)
2. search inside a cell that contains that range of values

for example:

- cell A1 contains the value 0.18 ~ 0.218
- cell B1 containes the value 125

I want to do a lookup so that if i search for 0.20 or 0.19 (which is within the range of cell A1) the value returned is 125.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
=IF(AND(VALUE(LEFT(A$1, FIND(" ", A$1&" ")))<=E2, VALUE(REPLACE(A$1, 1, FIND("~", A$1&"~"), ""))>=E2), B$1, "out of range")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try simple `if` statement:

```
=IF(AND(A1>0,18; A1<0,218); B1; )
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, `edit`ing to add a brief explanation might be more helpful to future readers, who may not be as familiar with excel's terse syntax works in this case.  Thanks for your contribution!